# Has Donald Duck ever had any love interest besides Daisy?

Tags: disney, donald-duck

A common trope in the *Duckverse* is Daisy double-dating Gladstone Gander and Donald at the same time, never fully committing to either one.

During the times when he wasn't with Daisy, has Donald Duck ever had any love interest besides Daisy?

Comment: For those voting to close, this question is [on topic per meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11530/58193).

Comment: What a marvelous question. <3

Comment: "Double-dating" usually involves two couples. If only the three of them are present, wouldn't that be more of a one-and-a-half date?

Comment: [Reginella](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Reginella) maybe?

Comment: Does love potions count? I recall a story where a female duck tries to flirt with Donald, so Daisy asks an inventor to create a love potion to "restore" their couple but Donald drinks it and falls in love with the first character he sees : the other female duck...

Comment: I still question the fact that Donald is a *duck*. Feel he ought to be Donald Drake - maybe descended from Sir Francis..?

Comment: Definitely yes, I clearly remember that in comics he had several crushes on somebody. I don't have any comics on me anymore, unfortunately.

Comment: There are various one-off stories where Donald has another love interest, but I'm not sure if those should count since in the end status quo is maintained (i.e., Donald messes it up somehow, or Daisy prevails if she's in the story).

Comment: Hmm, I suppose avoiding to answer in any way would count as ducking the question.. :/

Comment: @Tim The word "duck" is commonly used to refer to either gender, so that's not unusual.  What is disturbing is that when it's used as a last name, it implies that Donald and Daisy (or Donna) are already related even though they're not married.  Mickey and Minnie Mouse have the same problem.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - good point. Although should one believe in Adam and Eve, or later the story of Noah, that would point to humans being in the same sort of category, maybe..?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Not everyone named "Smith" is related to everyone else named "Smith" (at least not closely enough to cause concern). "Duck" seems to be an equally common surname in this universe.

Comment: @jmbpiano True, but it seems that only in cartoon world is it okay for almost every character's last name to simply be what kind of animal they are.  It's like if every human on Earth had to share the last name "Human".  Why even *have* last names in that case?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Because some are named McDuck or Glomgold.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Or as if Superman, Batman, Antman, Aquaman all had "man" in their names ;)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

## Yes, and no...

Donald Duck's first love interest was Donna Duck, first appearing in the *Don Donald* 1937 short film.

[image: Donna Duck as she appears in Don Donald]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

However, this is where things get confusing. Whilst she has appeared in comics alongside Daisy, Disney states that they are the same character.

[image: 1951 comic showing Daisy and Donna together] [image: Comic showing Daisy and Donna together]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

I can't actually find a copy online to get the quote from it (will keep looking) but apparently *Disney Dossiers: Files of Characters From the Walt Disney Studios* refers to them as the same character. In the *Walt Disney Cartoon Classics: Starring Donald and Daisy* VHS the *Don Donald* short was re-released and it mentions it stars Donald and Daisy. See the still below and the video after it.

[image: Title card for the Don Donald re-release]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

As such it would certainly appear that the characters were combined, even though they clearly aren't the same character.

## ...But also yes

We also have Reginella, the queen of an alien civilisation and the pair do love each other but are kept apart. However, they meet a few times and appear to be in love.

[image: Donald serenades Reginella]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: Donald seemed enamored with the Mexican girls in the [Gran Fiesta Tour Starring The Three Caballeros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gran_Fiesta_Tour_Starring_The_Three_Caballeros)

Comment: @LarsTech I just came here to mention his flirtation with Yaya!