# Why were Donna and Daisy Duck merged into the same character?

Tags: disney, donald-duck

Whilst doing research for [my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/223046/58193) to the question: [Has Donald Duck ever had any love interest besides Daisy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/223044/58193) I found out about Donna Duck. Donna appears a few times before eventually apparently being merged into Daisy Duck to be the same character.

[image: Title card for the Don Donald re-release]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Normally a character re-name/merge wouldn't be too much of a problem, if awkward, however, Donna and Daisy have appeared a few times ***together***.

[image: 1951 comic showing Daisy and Donna together] [image: Comic showing Daisy and Donna together]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

So, that offers up the question, **why were Donna and Daisy Duck merged into the same character?**

Comment: This thread on Twitter seems relevant https://twitter.com/biryanifan/status/1083490151970557953